# file_get_contents return & g t ; instead of <

Tags: php, wampserver

I Have this

```
 $this->CompileString_ = file_get_contents("test.html");
 echo $this->CompileString_;
```

**test.html**

```
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

The problem is that file_get_contents return `&gt;` instead of getting <

Why ?.

I'm using wampserver 2 with php 5.3.8

Comment: Maybe you can give us a piece of the text that you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: I add a test.html file in the example for more clarity

Comment: I have tryed your code and it seems to be ok. To me the function returns the "<" char. Could you be more explicit on what you really see? I mean...when you echo the string, you see this? &lt;div&lt;test&lt;/div&lt;

Comment: YEah exacly I see &lt;div&lt;test&lt;/div&lt;. The reason why I don't want that is beacause if I put some php code in the test.html, I will not be able to evaluate the php code if the open tag < is convert to &lt;

Comment: @Jean-Francois Is that your full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello try renaming the file to `test.txt` maybe php automatically encodes that for .html files.

Use `htmlentitydecode();`

```
   <?php
    $orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

    $a = htmlentities($orig);

    $b = html_entity_decode($a);

    echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

    echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now


    // For users prior to PHP 4.3.0 you may do this:
    function unhtmlentities($string)
    {
        // replace numeric entities
        $string = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
        $string = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'chr("\\1")', $string);
        // replace literal entities
        $trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
        $trans_tbl = array_flip($trans_tbl);
        return strtr($string, $trans_tbl);
    }

    $c = unhtmlentities($a);

    echo $c; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now

    ?>
```

Comment: I think you answered the wrong ask. The OP want to decode the characters and not to encode them.